# Manipulating a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, data-manipulation

I successfully imported from the web this `json` file, which looks like:

`[{"h_mag":"19.7","i_deg":"9.65","moid_au":"0.035"},{"h_mag":"20.5","i_deg":"14.52","moid_au":"0.028"},`
etc ...

I want to extract the values of the key `moid_au`, later compare `moid_au` with the key values of `h_mag`.

This works: `print(data[1]['moid_au'])`, but if I try to ask all the elements of the list it won't, I tried: `print(data[:]['moid_au'])`.

I tried iterators and a `lambda` function but still has not work yet, mostly because I'm new in data manipulation. It works when I have one dictionary, not with a list of dictionaries.

Thanks in advance for other tips. Some links were confusing.

Comment: You need a simple [`for` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Take a look at [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), there is also a section on [looping techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Comment: Hi Giacomo, the simple 'for ' loops I read on the web are for one dictionary, not for a "list" of dictionaries, I am having trouble how to access them.

Comment: You need to show the code you tried.

Comment: The links I provided explain looping over lists too. I would personally suggest that you find a good tutorial and stick with it instead of asking questions here right now. Asking questions when you don't know the language is going to waste way more time than reading a tutorial and following the exercises and you're going to get downvotes for not having done proper research before asking. If you have trouble with some point of a tutorial you can try to search for an answer and, eventually, ask a specific questions *linking to the tutorial* so that people can properly explain.

Comment: Hey! It was this 
for k in data.keys():
    print(data[k])

but someone below answered something simple that it works. I understand this is a beginners problem.

Comment: Hi Giacomo, I have followed the tutorial from datacamp but there is little info about json, besides we see so many things we lost how to connect the dots.

Comment: And by the way Giacomo, before posting this, I had exactly the same link you sent opened but I did not figure the answer. That's why we ask.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are using `lambda` wrong because you need `map` as well:

```
c = [{"h_mag":"19.7","i_deg":"9.65","moid_au":"0.035"},{"h_mag":"20.5","i_deg":"14.52","moid_au":"0.028"}]

list(map(lambda rec: rec.get('moid_au'), c))
['0.035', '0.028']
```

Each `lambda` grabs a record from your list and you map your function to that.

Comment: Why use get instead of regular indexing (`list(map(lambda rec: rec['moid_au'], c))`)?

Comment: one advantage is that it won't throw an error if they key does not exist

Comment: That's the only difference I know, and from my perspective, its not necessarily an advantage

Comment: ok, depending on the problem it could be, especially if you give it a default value, like `0` if you plan to plot the data as OP specified.

Answer (score 2):

Using `print(data[:]['moid_au'])` equals to `print(data['moid_au'])`, and you can see that it won't work, as `data` has no key named `'moid_au'`.

Try working with a loop:

```
for item in data:
    print(item['moid_au'])
```

Comment: Thanks ClsForCookies, this works. However the thing is not only to print it but to manipulate it, so I will try to see how to make it a variable I can play with.

Answer (score 2):

using your approach to iterate over the whole array to get all the instances of a key,this method might work for you

```
a = [data[i]['moid_au']for i in range(len(data))]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

In which exact way do you want to compare them?

Would it be useful getting the values in a way like this?

```
list_of_dicts = [{"h_mag":"19.7","i_deg":"9.65","moid_au":"0.035"}, {"h_mag":"20.5","i_deg":"14.52","moid_au":"0.028"}]
mod_au_values = [d["moid_au"] for d in list_of_dicts]
h_mag_values = [d["h_mag"] for d in list_of_dicts]
```

Comment: exactly that! Later I can do anything I want with these two variables (e.g. plot)

Comment: @IreneDelCarmenPérez-Merbis I'm glad I helped! If this answers your question completely I suggest you to mark it as accepted so others can see it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key,  value in my_list.items (): 
       print key
       print value
```

```
for value in my_list.values (): 
       print value
```

```
for key in my_list.keys():
       print key
```